# Update and insert data instead of complete replacement

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I use the code below to retrieve a XML and write the data to Sheet2.
But when i run the function again it loads the entire xml again into the sheet.

What i want to achieve, but don't know how:

1.
Get de XML and compare it with the data already in Sheet2, based on 2 colums:
stationID & stationTypeID

2.
When the two columns match, update the entire row. When the columns don't match, insert the new row on top.

```
  function loadOutposts(){
  var outposts= new Array();
  var url = "https://api.eveonline.com/eve/ConquerableStationList.xml.aspx";
  var parameters = {method : "get", payload : ""};
  var xmlFeed = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, parameters).getContentText();
  var xml = XmlService.parse(xmlFeed);
  if(xml) {
    var rows=xml.getRootElement().getChild("result").getChild("rowset").getChildren("row");
    for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      outpost=[rows[i].getAttribute("stationID").getValue(),
                 rows[i].getAttribute("stationName").getValue(),
                 rows[i].getAttribute("stationTypeID").getValue(),
                 rows[i].getAttribute("solarSystemID").getValue(),
                 rows[i].getAttribute("corporationID").getValue(),
                 rows[i].getAttribute("corporationName").getValue()
                 ]
      outposts.push(outpost);
    }
  }
  //return outposts;
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet2').getRange(1,1,outposts.length,outposts[0].length).setValues(outposts);
};
```

Thx for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Flow :

1. Data retrieved by `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` is compared to the existing data on Spreadsheet.
2. When the columns 1 and 2 for them are same, the existing data is updated.
3. When the data retrieved from URL is not included in the existing data, the data is inserted to the top of existing data. This existing data becomes new data.
4. Then, the data on Spreadsheet is updated by new data.

#### Modified script :

```
function loadOutposts(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet2');

  var outposts= new Array();
  var url = "https://api.eveonline.com/eve/ConquerableStationList.xml.aspx";
  var parameters = {method : "get", payload : ""};
  var xmlFeed = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, parameters).getContentText();
  var xml = XmlService.parse(xmlFeed);
  if (xml) {
    var rows=xml.getRootElement().getChild("result").getChild("rowset").getChildren("row");
    for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      outpost = [
        rows[i].getAttribute("stationID").getValue(),
        rows[i].getAttribute("stationName").getValue(),
        rows[i].getAttribute("stationTypeID").getValue(),
        rows[i].getAttribute("solarSystemID").getValue(),
        rows[i].getAttribute("corporationID").getValue(),
        rows[i].getAttribute("corporationName").getValue()
      ]
      outposts.push(outpost);
    }

    // ----- Added script
    if (ss.getLastRow() > 0) {
      var currentdata = ss.getRange(2, 1, ss.getLastRow(), ss.getLastColumn()).getValues(); // Updated
      currentdata.forEach(function(e1, i1){
        var temp = [];
        outposts.forEach(function(e2, i2){
          if (e1[0] == e2[0] && e1[1] == e2[1]) {
            currentdata[i1] = e2;
            temp.push(i2);
          }
        });
        for (var i in temp) {
          outposts.splice(temp[i], 1);
        }
      });
      Array.prototype.push.apply(outposts, currentdata);
    }
    // -----
  }
  ss.getRange(2,1,outposts.length,outposts[0].length).setValues(outposts);  // Updated
};
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, your solution works perfect :)
Big thanks, was trying already for a few days and now it works!

Comment: One more question, script works great but in sheet2 i need to skip the first row. There i have the column names. When i run the script it now duplicates the first row.

Comment: @user6079228 I updated my answer. Please confirm it. By this update, the first row is ignored.

Comment: perfect! Thanks again for the great help :)